# UIScrollView and UIPageControl within UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I've seen lots of sources saying it is possible to **include a UIScrollView with UIPageControl inside a UITableViewCell** to be able to **scroll horizontally** (through a list of selectable images), but can't find any raw examples that does what I want.  I've gotten my scroll view "working", but I am unsure how to go forward - hopefully someone can send me some guidance.

Within my cellForRowAtIndexPath, I create a cell, and add both a scrollView and pageControl as subviews.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.challengeListView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SubmitChallengeCellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SubmitChallengeCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 50);
    }   

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tv.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 50)];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:scrollView];

    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, tv.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [pageControl setNumberOfPages:4];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:pageControl];
```

I've attached a screenshot of what's being displayed

[image: something]

the bottom portion of the main view is my UITableView that contains the scrollView/pageControl (and it will scroll horizontally, as I can see the scrollerIndicator showing this), and I've got its method's set to the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    return 1;
}
```

My Scroll view will indicate a "**horizontalScroller**" and I am able to scroll back and forth, but obviously there's *no content* there.  **How do I go about populating the tableView/scrollView with say, a list of "clickable" images?  Any direction would be greatly appreciated** - preferably not a "hey this guy's done it somewhat similar, check out this link" but maybe more an explanation of how this functionality should be implemented correctly (E**SPECIALLY in regards to iOS 3.0+** - it is my understanding Apple has made our lives easier in implementing this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my own problem; maybe the reason no once answered me is because its a minor implementation once you understand each view's purpose.

From within `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` 
I created a standard `UITableViewCell`, however I altered the frame of the cell to my own custom frame of 1000 width by 50 height (catered to my needs for project).

I then created a `UIScrollView`, set it to the following (keep in mind I have my tableView defined in IB, so I'm mapping some of my height/widths to those values):

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tv.frame.size.width, 78)];
```

I then create the desired image view (I realize I will next create a loop that does many images and lays them out across the scroll view):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dummy.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 78);
[scrollView addSubview: imageView];
```

Here's the part I was missing. After adding the scrollView to the cell contents,  you need to use the `UIPageControl` (which didn't seem obvious to me for this implementation at first) to setup the actual "visual horizonal scrolling" affect:

```
   [[cell contentView] addSubview:scrollView];

pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, tv.frame.size.width, 50)];
[pageControl setNumberOfPages:4];
[[cell contentView] addSubview:pageControl];
```

Hope that helps someone's search - I spent quite some time on Google looking for the example I just explained and didn't have much luck other than the general overview of how it would work.

Comment: @user546459, i am searching for something like that..i want to scroll my uitableview horizontally so i can read all the text ..i hope u have an idea how to solve this..can you please check my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337669/scroll-uitableview-verticall-and-horizontally --thank you

Comment: To further clarify, I was able to remove all the tableView implementations, and just define a UIScrollView to do the work for me.  Found there was no reason to overdo it with the tableView.