# Trying to create an embedded scrolling section like seen in the RunKeeper IOS App

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm trying to create an embedded scrolling section like seen in the RunKeeper IOS App. An example is in this below where on the top of the graphic you can see the ability to scroll thru additional information. I am unable to find any tutorials that might help me understand this design. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, they have added UIPageControl inside the tableview 2nd cell.

these links might be helpful to you:

[UIScrollView and UIPageControl within UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092212/uiscrollview-and-uipagecontrol-within-uitableview)

http://pastebin.com/ZyR3U2BY